# The chrome .deb not working with the new software center?

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Google Chrome on 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64384/how-to-install-google-chrome-on-11-10)

I downloaded the .deb twice. I double click on it, the software center opens and it says "Internal error"

Please help.

Comment: This is a bug, see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64384/how-to-install-google-chrome-on-11-10

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon the same problem...

### Easy way

Simply install Chromium from the software center. It's the open-source version of Google Chrome.

### Somewhat harder way - Possibility 1

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Right-click the downloaded deb-file and choose *Open with Gdebi*.
Click the *Install package* button.

### Somewhat harder way - Posibility 2

```
cd Downloads
sudo dpkg -i chrome.deb
```

Replace *chrome.deb*  by the correct filename.